# Why does linking with -no-pie stop segment traps in constructors in programes built with GCC 13?

Tags: gcc

I have 20 projects that build and function correctly with GCC 10, 11 & 12. Debian testing (Trixie, version 13) uses GCC 13. I am in the process of fixing the new warnings that are thrown up by GCC 13.

One of the projects (approx 3K sloc + 17 rebuilt libraries) segment traps before main. Using GDB I found it was in executing the constructors. I have eliminated the non-compiler generated ones. I was preparing to use an ICE to investigate futher, so did the final link with -no-pie (as the ICE is incompatible with ASR), and the problem went away. My first thought was that it was a debian patch to GCC 13, so I built GCC from source without patches and had no change to the symptoms.

With GCC 7, 8 & 9 there used to be a generic problem that -g made stuff work when desired functionality was incorrectly optimised out. I am wondering if anybody else has seen this generic problem or if anybody has any suggestions as to where to look.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.